# Reading remote txt file with ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, readfile

I'm creating a banner for my website from Flash, and I'm using Action Script to read information from a file to put that info on the banner

Now this seems to work fine for local files. But the file will not be on the same server as the script and banner.. (personal Reasons).

How can I read this remote text file?
this text files location would be something like: http://www.some-server.com/text_file.txt
this file is freely readable for anyone..

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need any security sandbox exceptions or anything. Just use a URLLoader:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.some-server.com/text_file.txt"));

private function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var fileContents:String = String(e.currentTarget.data);
}
```